# how to add a break point in bootstrap for displaying in mobile?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a website created in bootstrap. How can I add a break point in that so that it will be displayed in mobiles of small screen size. I need to know which class I can add to make my website display in small devices.

Answer (score 0):

you can find all the classes on bootsrap's website
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options